# Application vs. local state in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In many Redux examples, `SOME_ASYNC_ACTION_ERROR` or `SOME_ASYNC_PENDING` are actions that are dispatched to manipulate the global state. I can't think of a scenario where it would make sense for a component to be initially rendered with a global error / loading / pending state. When a component is destroyed and remounted, that async error would need to be "cleared", making it seem like manipulating the component's *local state* is a better choice.

Considering this, what's the best practice for dealing with loading / error / pending states in Redux:

- Should a component default to an initial state locally but still subscribe to the global application state for loading / errors?
- OR Should the application state for error / loading be reset after leaving a component?
- OR Should these transitory states just be managed locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, the best practice in Redux is to always store application in the global store, but then have your individual components subscribe to only the relevant information from that store, using `connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)`. So rather than having a global application `loading` property, your individual components would subscribe to the relevant flag, such as `users.loading`

See http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html for more

EDIT: To further answer your question, each Action should clean up after itself, by dispatching another action. So you might have `REQUEST_USER` which adds a loading flag and resets an error state, followed by `RECEIVE_USER`, which removes the loading flag, or `FAILED_TO_RECIEVE_USER`, which removes the loading flag, buts adds an error state. This pattern is described pretty thoroughly here: https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#redux-standard-api-calling-actions

Comment: Correct, this is all assuming that `connect` is being used to map the appropriate application state to the component -- I should have specified that. The issue still remains w/ the error / pending states.

Comment: I edited my answer above to cover this a little further, I should have addressed that to start with

Comment: And...if you don't think the "error" state should survive after a component is unmounted, then you need to look at the action which caused the Redux store to update which caused a React re-render which caused your component to be unmounted.  Your components just don't go and unmount themselves for no reason.  They do it because the Redux store was modified due to an action.  Most likely you need a reducer for that action which clears the error state in addition to whatever else it does.